# mongodb in-memory sort with projection or limit

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I'm running a query against MongoDB (3.2 in my case) with a sort, and I'm getting:

```
OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM.
```

I understand that I can use an index to avoid this. In my case this is an operation that I run very rarely, so the overhead of an index doesn't make sense (it's also fine if this operation takes a long time and consumes a lot of resources). I'm pretty sure I'll end up using an aggregation with `allowDiskUse` to work around this, but I was curious about something.

I'm curious whether using a projection can reduce the memory footprint required by the in-memory sort. Similarly I'm wondering whether a `limit()` can reduce this footprint (since the sort only needs to keep the top/bottom N in memory).

Comment: Use and Index to Avoid It. If you understand that then do it. The overhead of an index makes perfect sense since it's designed to avoid this exact problem.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, Imagine that I use this database every day all day with millions of updates to fields that are covered by the index. Then imagine that this one slow query needs to be run once a month, and I can wait hours for it to finish. In this case it doesn't make sense to pay for the index all the time when I don't really need it (from a performance point of view).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your collection is not indexed, projection will not be able to help you sidestep the in-memory sort 32 MB limit. On the other hand, `limit()` can help you if the resulting result set is less than 32 MB in size.

**Note** This answer concerns only the regular `find()` method, and not the corresponding `$match` + `$sort` + `$limit` aggregation stages.

#### Unindexed Find + Projection + Sort

The [Interaction with Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#interaction-with-projection) documentation mentions:

> When a set of results are both sorted and projected, the MongoDB query engine will always apply the sorting first.

This can be shown using the [explain() method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/). For example, consider an unindexed collection containing documents in the form of:

```
{"a": <a short string>, "b": <a large 10 MB value>}
```

the `explain()` result of a sort with projection outputs:

```
> db.coll.explain().find({},{a:1}).sort({a:1})
    ...
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "PROJECTION",
      "transformBy": {
        "a": 1
      },
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "SORT",
        "sortPattern": {
          "a": 1
        },
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "COLLSCAN",
            "direction": "forward"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

From the `explain()` output, the stages of the query goes in the order of:

```
COLLSCAN -> SORT -> PROJECTION
```

This means that projection will not be able to help you when your result set size exceeds 32 MB.

Running the query thus resulted in the expected failure:

```
> db.coll.find({},{a:1}).sort({a:1})
Error: error: {
  "ok": 0,
  "errmsg": "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
  "code": 96,
  "codeName": "OperationFailed"
}
```

#### Unindexed Find + Limit + Sort

The [Limit results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#limit-results) documentation mentions:

> If MongoDB cannot obtain the sort order via an index scan, then MongoDB uses a top-k sort algorithm. This algorithm buffers the first k results (or last, depending on the sort order) seen so far by the underlying index or collection access. If at any point the memory footprint of these k results exceeds 32 megabytes, the query will fail.

The `limit()` will help in this regard only if the total result set to be sorted is still under 32 MB.

For example (using the 10 MB per document example above), doing a

```
`find({}, <projection>).limit(3).sort(...)`
```

will work, since the total size that needs to be sorted is 3x10 MB == 30 MB.

However, doing

`find({}, <projection>).limit(4).sort(...)`

will fail, since the result set will contain 4x10 MB == 40 MB. The projection does not matter in both cases, only the result set total size to be sorted.

Note that using projection does not affect the memory usage of the query. Only the size of the result set that needs to be sorted matters.

Comment: Since the limit docs say it only keeps `k` items in memory, shouldn't the limit help me here? For example if I make the limit 1, shouldn't it succeed (as long as one doc fits in RAM)? I tried this and still get that same error, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I updated the answer with better `limit()` explanation.

Comment: I think your opening sentence needs to change as well, other than that this answer is great, thank you!

Comment: I restructured the answer so that it's easier to follow. Please accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an index for the sort parameters.
Ex:

```
db.collection.find({ .... }).projection({...}).sort({ code: 1, name: 1 });
db.collection.createIndex({ code: 1, name: 1 }, collation: { locale: 'en'})
```

This way you avoid exceeding the limit of memory for sort (32mb), but if your case each entry document is big, you can increase this limit.

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryExecMaxBlockingSortBytes: 33554432}) // 32mb
```